# What happens on stack overflow when you modify the form fkey?

Tags: security, csrf

What does a popular programming site do when you change the xsrf token value?

Comment: why don't you try and see it? it would also be interesting if copying the key and sending back from code will let you submit forms automatically.

Comment: It sounded like a joke with a really bad punch-line before I clicked into it.

Comment: It's quite interesting to me that SO lets the form post continue. What got me thinking about this was reading Jeff's post from a while back on XSRF protection: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html. He talks about SO using a unique token per form, which appears to no longer be the case. In addition, modifying the token in the form appears to have no effect. Due to his stance on XSRF, this is curious to me.

Comment: We all know SO has poor secuirty,  but you should have worded this question differently.   The two most common approaches are:  to die before the application performs any action or to unset GET/POST variables.

Answer (score 3):

The answer, when I modify it with Firebug, seems to be "nothing... it accepts the form post"

Comment: we weren't checking this on /questions/ask/submit -- but we do everywhere else. Just an oversight, thanks for the heads up!